# How to update django model fields without knowing which fields to be updated beforehand?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to update a model without knowing which fields to update beforehand.
For example:
The request to my url `api/user/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/message-update/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/` will have a payload JSON with a POST request method like this:

```
{
"category": "personal",
"type_of_transaction": "paid"
}
```

The problem here is that the payload key-value pairs will keep changing depending upon the fields to be changed.

I have tried this but it seems to have no effect at all:

```
message = Message.objects.get(user=pk, id=id)
json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode(encoding='UTF-8'))
attributes_to_be_changed = json_data.keys()
values = json_data.values()
for i in attributes_to_be_changed:
    message.i = values[attributes_to_be_changed.index(i)]
message.save(update_fields=attributes_to_be_changed)
try:
    json_message = MessageSerializer(Message, many=False)
except Exception as e:
    return JsonResponse({"error": e})
return JsonResponse(json_message.data, safe=False)
```

I have a message model as below:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages')
sender = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
body = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
account = models.ForeignKey(Account, blank=True, null=True)
card = models.ForeignKey(CreditCard, blank=True, null=True)
type_of_transaction = models.CharField(max_length=10)
message_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
category = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
spent_at = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
meta = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
amount = models.FloatField()
lat = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="null")
lon = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="null")

def __str__(self):
    try:
        state = "Message from "+self.account.name+" for "+self.user.username
    except Exception:
        state = "Message from "+ self.card.card_number+"for"+self.user.username
    return state
```

My serializer:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    account = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_account(self, obj):
        try:
            name = obj.account.name
        except Exception:
            name = obj.card.card_number
        return name

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('id','sender','body','account','category','spent_at','meta','type_of_transaction', 'amount', 'message_date')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think in your case you should use setattr

```
for key, value in json_data.items():
    setattr(message, key, value)
```

Or maybe update_or_create could be a good idea, too
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

defaults is your json_data

Comment: After trying this I am getting a error `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'` . Here is the full traceback https://paste.ubuntu.com/26520109/

Comment: After checking through admin, I realized the message has been changed successfully, then I guess, the serializer is causing the error. I am adding the serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
# Note: if id field is primary key, you don´t need to consult by user also

message_updated = Message.objects.filter(user=pk, id=id).update(**json_data)
```

Comment: It says `'Message' object has no attribute 'update'`. FYI I am using Django 1.11. And thumbs up for the primary key correction.

Comment: That's right, excuse me ... the update method is only applicable to QuerySet objects. You can change .get to .filter method or ... (wait a moment)

Comment: Please check the serializer edits. I am pretty sure that's what is causing the error as the message is being successfully saved.

Comment: @Rahul can you share the MessageSerializer code? (You should not control that exception since it can only occur in a programming error)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
It was a typo in `json_message = MessageSerializer(Message, many=False)`. 
Replaced `Message` with `message` and got it working.
It was previously taking the model as an argument.